# Trouble finding last column from a data-ridden sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I've tried to figure out the last used column in my excel spreadsheet using VBA to start writing something right after that column. In the image below I've tried to show what I meant and where I wanna start writing from. The desired field is already selected there which is "F2".

However, the problem is the data already available there did not maintain uniformity. How can I figure out the last used column using VBA?

This is my try:

```
Sub FindLastColumn()
    Dim lCol&

    lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    MsgBox lCol
End Sub
```

It produces `8` as result which is not correct as the right one should be `5`.

The data-ridden sheet looks like below:

[image]

Comment: try to delete data from status column up to the end in case there is any character.also have a look to my answer may help you.

Comment: Your code gets the last used column for row 1, which is in fact 8 according to your image, if you changed the row number from 1 to 2, you would get 2, as that is the last column with data on Row 2... Whereas in row 6 you would get 5..etc..

Comment: Then how can I write something in that selected cells without hardcoding the `Range()` @Xabier?

Comment: I don't see any variation between what I've pasted above and what you have suggested in your solution @Error 1004.

Comment: @asmitu at your post you dont defined from which work sheet you want to take last column. Additionally, without mentioning work sheet you may receive wrong answers because code use the active sheet to run the code.

Comment: Don't get me wrong @Error 1004. My question is not about writing a fully qualified line of code. Thanks.

Comment: @asmitu i m not trying to confuse you,you are trying to get the last column of row 1.Your worksheet clearly show that your first row have titles which cover the first 8 columns.so the answer the code give you is correct!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to find the right-hand most used column in rows 2 to the end of your data. To do that, you'll need to loop through all the rows of data keeping track of which column is `Max(LastUsedColumn)`. Unfortunately, there is no such built in function, but you could write one something like this:

```
Public Function MaxUsedColumnInRow(ByVal SheetToCheck As Worksheet, ByVal RowToCheck As Long) As Long
  MaxUsedColumnInRow = SheetToCheck.Cells(RowToCheck, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End Function
```

Now that you have a nifty function to determine which is the maximum used column in a row, you can call it in a loop, like this:

```
Public Function MaxUsedColumnInRange(ByVal SheetToCheck As Worksheet, ByVal StartRow As Long, ByVal EndRow As Long) As Long

  Dim curRow As Long
  For curRow = StartRow To EndRow
    Dim CurCol As Long
    CurCol = MaxUsedColumnInRow(SheetToCheck, curRow)
    Dim maxCol As Long
    If CurCol > maxCol Then
      maxCol = CurCol
    End If
  Next

End Function
```

And, finally, give it a quick test replacing "Sheet1" with the name of the worksheet you're specifically checking:

```
Public Sub TestIt()
  MsgBox "Max Used column on sheet1 = " & CStr(MaxUsedColumnInRange("Sheet1", 2, 50))
End Sub
```

Of course, you'll want to determine the max used *row* on your sheet and pass that into the the `MaxUsedColumnInRange` function - unless you happen to have exactly 50 rows of data, the example test `Sub` probably won't get you your actual desired result.

As a side benefit, you now have a handy function you can call in the future to determine the max column in a row so you don't have to remember the proper way of doing it. (I usually forget so I have to look it up, or use a nifty helper function to "remember" for me.)

Comment: You might be able to use `UsedRange.Rows.Count`. I know most people don't like to use it, though because OP could have data below this 'section' that we don't see

Comment: True, @Marcucciboy2, but I'll leave it to the OP to determine how many rows of data to check. There may be something _below_ this particular set of data that he doesn't want tested. I've seen it before...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the last column in your range excluding the header, you could achieve that as below, amend the Sheet name from Sheet1 to the Sheet you are actually using:

```
Sub foo()
LastRow = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
'get the last row with data in your used range
MaxCol = 1
For i = 2 To LastRow 'loop from row 2 to last
    If Sheet1.Cells(i, Sheet1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column > MaxCol Then
        MaxCol = Sheet1.Cells(i, Sheet1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        'get the highest value for the column into variable
    End If
Next i
MsgBox MaxCol
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy route would be to use `Find` like below:

```
Dim rgLastColumnCell As Range
Set rgLastColumnCell = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
MsgBox "Last Used Column is : " & rgLastColumnCell.Column
```

Adjust `ActiveSheet.Cells` portion to suit your need like: `Activesheet.Range("B2:XFD1048576")` if you want to skip first row from the check.

Answer (score 1):

Use a variation of the `Find` method of finding it, but limit it to ignore row 1:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = LastCell(Sheet1)

    MsgBox "Last cell containing data is " & rng.Address & vbCr & _
           "Selected cell is in example is " & Sheet1.Cells(2, rng.Column + 1).Address

End Sub

Public Function LastCell(wrkSht As Worksheet) As Range

    Dim lLastCol As Long, lLastRow As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    With wrkSht.Rows("2:1048576")
            lLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
            lLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

        If lLastCol = 0 Then lLastCol = 1
        If lLastRow = 0 Then lLastRow = 1

        Set LastCell = wrkSht.Cells(lLastRow, lLastCol)

    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the result you require by using built-in functions, either you can get the column H because it is the last used column or the column B, because it is the last filled column, To get E you have to write your own code, and by the look of it, it seems that you want the end of the colored range. You can check the last column where color is not present in a loop

```
Sub checkLastColumn()
    col_num = 1
    Do While Cells(2, col_num).Interior.Pattern <> xlNone
        col_num = col_num + 1
    Loop
    MsgBox col_num
End Sub
```

It will return column F

EDIT....

As I said earlier you cannot get the cell you require by any built-in function, you have to write some code, and in order to do that you must have a definite logic that should be known and decided between you and the users of the sheet.

For example:

- you can color the range as you have already done
- You can name the column header, as in your example, it is status.
- You can fix the number of data columns and status columns, and there will be no need to use any code

For finding the status column or any other if you decide you can use a loop as below

```
Sub getStatusColumn()
    col_num = 1
    Do While Cells(1, col_num) <> "status"
        col_num = col_num + 1
    Loop
    MsgBox col_num
End Sub
```

OR

```
Sub getLastItemColumn()
    col_num = 1
    Do While Left(Cells(1, col_num), 4) = "Item"
        col_num = col_num + 1
    Loop
    MsgBox col_num
End Sub
```

Comment: If I wouldn't differentiate the data and the header with the current fill then the post would be a vague one that is why I used those colors. In reality there is no colors except for the default one @usmanhaq. Thanks.

Comment: What if someone forgets to add some shading to existing data? However, this is a clever idea based on the posted screenshot.

Comment: @asmitu I have edited my post, you can check my comments

Comment: @FreeMan
You have a valid point, if a sheet is to be edited by multiple user, people tend to do many thing with sheets, and in such cases I usually try to make a design which is robust enough to withstand such mistakes.

In this case I would have gone for separating user input from status, but at the end it really goes to a comparison of how much effort you are putting on a solution and how much benefit you are getting.